# how to dynamically add multiple checkboxes to an html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want  to dynamically add checkboxes to multiple rows in an html table, without having to add input type ="checkbox" for  each . Is this possible?
The code snippet for making the table and  a function 'check()' to add check boxes is given below...but it does not work. please help.

```js
// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data.

function buildHtmlTable(myList) {
  var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    var row$ = $('<tr/>');
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
      var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

      if (cellValue == null) {
        cellValue = "";
      }

      row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));

    }
    
    $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
  }

}

// Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.

function addAllColumnHeaders(myList) {
  var columnSet = [];
  var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    var rowHash = myList[i];
    for (var key in rowHash) {
      if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
        columnSet.push(key);
        headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
        //check();
      }
      // check();
    }
    //check();
  }
  $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

  return columnSet;
  check();

}

function check() {
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    $('<input />', {
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 'id' + i,
      })
      .appendTo("#excelDataTable");
  }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to append checkboxes to `#excelDataTable` (I assume this is a `table`), that is the problem. You should append them into `td`s, not `table`

Comment: okay...but how do we do that?

Comment: can you please do the above said change in my code?

Comment: What he meant is, replace  .appendTo("#excelDataTable"); to   .appendTo("td");

Comment: Can you add an example data of `myList`? That would help a lot to test the code

Comment: @er-han 


var myList=  [
 {
   "ASN": "AS9498 BHARTI Airtel Ltd.",
   "COUNTRY": "IN",
   "IP": "182.72.211.158\n"
 },
 {
   "ASN": "AS9874 StarHub Broadband",
   "COUNTRY": "SG",
   "IP": "183.90.37.224"
 },
 {
   "ASN": "AS45143 SINGTEL MOBILE INTERNET SERVICE PROVIDER Singapore",
   "COUNTRY": "SG",
   "IP": "14.100.132.200"
 },
 {
   "ASN": "AS45143 SINGTEL MOBILE INTERNET SERVICE PROVIDER Singapore",
   "COUNTRY": "SG",
   "IP": "14.100.134.235"
 }]

Comment: @HemaNandagopal I tried that...it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the checkboxes after the table is created.
Below, you can see the updated code. Your table creation works perfect. But you were trying to append the checkboxes to the table itself, not td elements.

In `$(document).ready` function below, you can see that I create the table first and after that call `check()` function. It basicly creates a new `checkbox` for each row, wraps it in a `td` and put that into the `row`.

I also added a `change` event method for the first checkbox to control all the others.

```js
// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data.

function buildHtmlTable(myList) {
  var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    var row$ = $('<tr/>');
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
      var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

      if (cellValue == null) {
        cellValue = "";
      }

      row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));

    }

    $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
  }

}

// Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.

function addAllColumnHeaders(myList) {
  var columnSet = [];
  var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    var rowHash = myList[i];
    for (var key in rowHash) {
      if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
        columnSet.push(key);
        headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
        //check();
      }
      // check();
    }
    //check();
  }
  $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);



  return columnSet;
  //check();

}

function check() {
// foreach row in the table
// we create a new checkbox
// and wrap it with a td element
// then put that td at the beginning of the row

  var $rows = $('#excelDataTable tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < $rows.length; i++) {
    var $checkbox = $('<input />', {
      type: 'checkbox',
      id: 'id' + i,
    });

    $checkbox.wrap('<td></td>').parent().prependTo($rows[i]);
  }
  
  
  // First checkbox changes all the others
  $('#id0').change(function(){
  var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
  $('#excelDataTable input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', isChecked);
  })

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var myList = [{
    "ASN": "AS9498 BHARTI Airtel Ltd.",
    "COUNTRY": "IN",
    "IP": "182.72.211.158\n"
  }, {
    "ASN": "AS9874 StarHub Broadband",
    "COUNTRY": "SG",
    "IP": "183.90.37.224"
  }, {
    "ASN": "AS45143 SINGTEL MOBILE INTERNET SERVICE PROVIDER Singapore",
    "COUNTRY": "SG",
    "IP": "14.100.132.200"
  }, {
    "ASN": "AS45143 SINGTEL MOBILE INTERNET SERVICE PROVIDER Singapore",
    "COUNTRY": "SG",
    "IP": "14.100.134.235"
  }]


  buildHtmlTable(myList);
  check();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="excelDataTable"></table>
```

Comment: yea! got the concept...Thank you SOOO MUCH..! :) @er-han

Comment: @AshweshAnand i am glad to help :)